# three dimensional array from excel anylogic

Tags: arrays, excel, anylogic

I want to fill a three dimensional parameter with values from an excel sheet.
So for every year I need the CFS values of each month and safe it in this parameter but i don't know how to do this.

I already created the parameter with the three dimensions year, month, bins.

[Datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Vcm.png)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 15 years, 12 months and 12 bins:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++ )
{
   for( int j = 0 ; j < 12; j++ )
   {
      for( int k = 0 ; k < 12 ; k++ )
      {
        p[i][j][k] = excelFile.getCellNumericValue( 1 , 7 + j*12 + k, i + 3);
      }
   }
}
```